# How can I execute a function pointer that's pointing to a class method inside a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I want a function that can be called inside of another class which has a single input parameter of type void function pointer. Inside the function, the function pointer should execute the function to which it's pointing.

```
// inside TestClass.h
class TestClass
{
public:
    template<class UserClass>
    static void TestingFctPtrStatic(void (UserClass::* TestFunction)(void), UserClass* Object);
};

template<class UserClass>
inline void TestClass::TestingFctPtrStatic(void (UserClass::* TestFunction)(void), UserClass* Object)
{
    Object->TestFunction();
}
```

Calling the function inside the constructor of TestClass like this gives me the following compile error:

```
// inside TestClass.cpp
TestClass::TestClass()
{
    TestClass::TestingFctPtrStatic<TestClass>(&TestClass::PrintStuff, this);
}
```

With PrintStuff():

```
void TestClass::PrintStuff()
{
    std::cout << "Printing stuff!" << std::endl;
}
```

error C2039: 'TestFunction': is not a member of 'TestClass'
message : see declaration of 'TestClass'
message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void TestClass::TestingFctPtrStatic(void (__cdecl TestClass::* )(void),UserClass *)' being compiled
with
[
UserClass=TestClass
]

**Edit:**

I fixed it by using more parentheses in the implementation:

```
template<class UserClass>
inline void TestClass::TestingFctPtrStatic(void (UserClass::* TestFunction)(void), UserClass* Object)
{
    (Object->*TestFunction)();
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke may be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

```
void(UserClass::* TestFunction)(void)
```

This is not a pointer to a function. It is a pointer to a class method.

```
TestFunction();
```

You can't just call a class method out of thin air. You need an object, an instance of the class, whose method gets called. If `p` is a pointer to a `UserClass`, in other words:

```
UserClass *p=(points to somewhere);
```

then you would invoke its method using this syntax:

```
(p->*TestFunction)();
```

It is unclear from your question's description where the object whose method gets invoked comes from, so you need to figure it out, yourself, based on all the other information you have but was not included in the question. In some form or fashion you'll need to find a `UserClass` object, somewhere -- either passed in as an additional parameter, or it's lying around, somewhere, in the general vicinity -- and then you can use the `TestFunction` pointer to invoke this object's method.

This is fundamental to C++, provided that this is a class method. If this `PrintStuff` is a `static` class method, then this would be, indeed, a plain old function pointer:

```
void (*TestFunction)();
```

And it would get invoke, via a pointer, no differently than any other function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my post because I get new error messages which I can't resolve.

Comment: You need to compare, carefully, what you "updated", versus what I wrote, and the example I gave. A visual comparison reveals a major difference from my example of the correct syntax to invoke a class method through a pointer, and the "updated" version. Furthermore, if you have a new, follow-up question it's better to ask a new question on Stackoverflow instead of editing an existing one.